# Delete the first two characters in a JSON flat object inside an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I have this JSON flat array with 1 object inside:

```js
const jsonFile = [ { "0.id": 1, "0.details.first_name": "Gary", "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz", "0.details.nicknames.0.language": "italian", "0.details.nicknames.0.value": "martello", "0.details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese", "0.details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer", "0.details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz", "0.details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru", "0.country": "Indonesia", "0.modified": "2015-05-16", "0.vip": false, "1.id": 2, "1.details.first_name": "Carl", "1.details.last_name": "Jones", "1.details.nicknames.0.language": "danish", "1.details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge", "1.details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich", "1.details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge", "1.details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net", "1.details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru", "1.country": "Taiwan", "1.modified": "2325-05-16", "1.vip": false, "2.id": 3, "2.details.first_name": "Michael", "2.details.last_name": "Smith", "2.details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese", "2.details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd", "2.details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian", "2.details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer", "2.details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr", "2.details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com", "2.country": "Japan", "2.modified": "1235-44-44", "2.vip": true } ] 

// I've flatted this object using this function: 

JSON.flatten = function(data) {
    var result = {};
    function recurse (cur, prop) {
        if (Object(cur) !== cur) {
            result[prop] = cur;
        } else if (Array.isArray(cur)) {
             for(var i=0, l=cur.length; i<l; i++)
                 recurse(cur[i], prop ? prop+""+i : ""+i);
            if (l == 0)
                result[prop] = [];
        } else {
            var isEmpty = true;
            for (var p in cur) {
                isEmpty = false;
                recurse(cur[p], prop ? prop+""+p : p);
                
            }
            if (isEmpty)
                result[prop] = {};
        }
    }
    recurse(data, "");
    return result;
}

let finalFlat = JSON.flatten(jsonFile)

console.log(finalFlat)
```

I need to remove the first two characters of every element of the object.

For example, this:

```js
"0.id": 1,
"0.details.first_name": "Gary",
"0.details.last_name": "Ortiz",
```

Needs to become this:

```js
"id": 1,
"details.first_name": "Gary",
"details.last_name": "Ortiz",
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this? I've tried splice and map but they don't work because it's an object and not an array.

Comment: do you use the numbers as indices? please add the wanted result.

Comment: This is not [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). That's an object (wrapped in an array)

Comment: Why is this an object whose properties are paths instead of an object with the respective structure (an array of persons)?

Comment: I added missing commas and made a [mcve] from your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using `Object.entries`, you can generate [key, value] pair from each object.
- Using `Array.reduce`, you can generate the result object which takes 2 chars from key.

```js
const input = [ { "0.id": 1, "0.details.first_name": "Gary", "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz", "0.details.nicknames.0.language": "italian", "0.details.nicknames.0.value": "martello", "0.details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese", "0.details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer", "0.details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz", "0.details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru", "0.country": "Indonesia", "0.modified": "2015-05-16", "0.vip": false, "1.id": 2, "1.details.first_name": "Carl", "1.details.last_name": "Jones", "1.details.nicknames.0.language": "danish", "1.details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge", "1.details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich", "1.details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge", "1.details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net", "1.details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru", "1.country": "Taiwan", "1.modified": "2325-05-16", "1.vip": false, "2.id": 3, "2.details.first_name": "Michael", "2.details.last_name": "Smith", "2.details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese", "2.details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd", "2.details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian", "2.details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer", "2.details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr", "2.details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com", "2.country": "Japan", "2.modified": "1235-44-44", "2.vip": true } ] 

const result = input.map((item) => (Object.entries(item).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const indexKey = cur[0].substring(0, 2);
  if (!acc[indexKey]) { acc[indexKey] = {}; }
  acc[indexKey][cur[0].substring(2)] = cur[1];
  return acc;
}, {}))).map((item) => Object.values(item)).flat();
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the array only has one element, you don't need a `flatten` function, you can just take the first and only element. Then you assign the values to a new object with the modified keys:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "0.id": 1,
    "0.details.first_name": "Gary",
    "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz"
  }
];

var dataObject = data[0];
var result = {};
Object.entries(dataObject).forEach(entry => {
    var [key, value] = entry;
    var newKey = key.substring(2);
    result[newKey] = value;
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build objects or arrays, depending on the value.

```js
const
    setValue = (object, path, value) => {
        let keys = path.split('.'),
            last = keys.pop();

        keys
            .reduce((o, k, i, kk) =>
                o[k] = o[k] || (isFinite(i + 1 in kk ? kk[i + 1] : last) ? [] : {}), object)
            [last] = value;
    },
    data = [{ "0.id": 1, "0.details.first_name": "Gary", "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz", "0.details.nicknames.0.language": "italian", "0.details.nicknames.0.value": "martello", "0.details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese", "0.details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer", "0.details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz", "0.details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru", "0.country": "Indonesia", "0.modified": "2015-05-16", "0.vip": false, "1.id": 2, "1.details.first_name": "Carl", "1.details.last_name": "Jones", "1.details.nicknames.0.language": "danish", "1.details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge", "1.details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich", "1.details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge", "1.details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net", "1.details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru", "1.country": "Taiwan", "1.modified": "2325-05-16", "1.vip": false, "2.id": 3, "2.details.first_name": "Michael", "2.details.last_name": "Smith", "2.details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese", "2.details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd", "2.details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian", "2.details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer", "2.details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr", "2.details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com", "2.country": "Japan", "2.modified": "1235-44-44", "2.vip": true }],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => setValue(r, k, v));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of elements you can do it like so:

```
let final = []
Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  let firstDot = key.indexOf('.')
  let id = key.substring(0, firstDot);
  if(!final[id]){
    final.push({})
  }
  final[id][key.substring(firstDot + 1)] = data[key]
  
})
console.log(final)
```

Run on : https://jsbin.com/libevevanu/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly delete the first 2 characters of your json since their will be duplicate keys (ex: `"0.id": 1,` and `"1.id": 2,`)
However, here is a small script to change this object:

```js
{
    "0.id": 1,
    "0.details.first_name": "Gary",
    "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz",
    "0.details.nicknames.0.language": "italian",
    "0.details.nicknames.0.value": "martello",
    "0.details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese",
    "0.details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer",
    "0.details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz",
    "0.details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru",
    "0.country": "Indonesia",
    "0.modified": "2015-05-16",
    "0.vip": false
    "1.id": 2,
    "1.details.first_name": "Carl",
    "1.details.last_name": "Jones",
    "1.details.nicknames.0.language": "danish",
    "1.details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge",
    "1.details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich",
    "1.details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge",
    "1.details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net",
    "1.details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru",
    "1.country": "Taiwan",
    "1.modified": "2325-05-16",
    "1.vip": false
    "2.id": 3,
    "2.details.first_name": "Michael",
    "2.details.last_name": "Smith",
    "2.details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese",
    "2.details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd",
    "2.details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian",
    "2.details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer",
    "2.details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr",
    "2.details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com",
    "2.country": "Japan",
    "2.modified": "1235-44-44",
    "2.vip": true
}
```

into this one:

```js
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "details.first_name": "Gary",
        "details.last_name": "Ortiz",
        "details.nicknames.0.language": "italian",
        "details.nicknames.0.value": "martello",
        "details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese",
        "details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer",
        "details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz",
        "details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru",
        "country": "Indonesia",
        "modified": "2015-05-16",
        "vip": false
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "details.first_name": "Carl",
        "details.last_name": "Jones",
        "details.nicknames.0.language": "danish",
        "details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge",
        "details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich",
        "details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge",
        "details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net",
        "details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru",
        "country": "Taiwan",
        "modified": "2325-05-16",
        "1.vip": false
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "details.first_name": "Michael",
        "details.last_name": "Smith",
        "details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese",
        "details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd",
        "details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian",
        "details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer",
        "details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr",
        "details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com",
        "country": "Japan",
        "modified": "1235-44-44",
        "vip": true
    }
]
```

Script:

```js
const yourObject = {...};
const subObjects = {};
for (const key in yourObject) {
    const [indice, ...subKey] = key.split('.');
    if (!indice in subObjects) {
        subObjects[indice] = {};
    }
    subObject[indice][subKey.join('.')] = yourObject[key];
}
// I assume you don't skip a number in your initial object
// -> If there is "3.", then there are "0.", "1." and "2."
const array = [];
for (let indice=0; indice<Object.keys(subObjects).length; indice++) {
    array.push(subObject[indice]);
};

console.log(array); // <- Your list of sub objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const yourJson = [
    {
        "0.id": 1,
        "0.details.first_name": "Gary",
        "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz",
        "0.details.nicknames.0.language": "italian",
        "0.details.nicknames.0.value": "martello",
        "0.details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese",
        "0.details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer",
        "0.details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz",
        "0.details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru",
        "0.country": "Indonesia",
        "0.modified": "2015-05-16",
        "0.vip": false,
        "1.id": 2,
        "1.details.first_name": "Carl",
        "1.details.last_name": "Jones",
        "1.details.nicknames.0.language": "danish",
        "1.details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge",
        "1.details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich",
        "1.details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge",
        "1.details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net",
        "1.details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru",
        "1.country": "Taiwan",
        "1.modified": "2325-05-16",
        "1.vip": false,
        "2.id": 3,
        "2.details.first_name": "Michael",
        "2.details.last_name": "Smith",
        "2.details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese",
        "2.details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd",
        "2.details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian",
        "2.details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer",
        "2.details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr",
        "2.details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com",
        "2.country": "Japan",
        "2.modified": "1235-44-44",
        "2.vip": true
    }
]

const result = Object.keys(js[0]).reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key.slice(2)] = js[0][key];
    return acc;
}, {});
```

NB: If you remove the first two characters the final list will be 1/3rd of the original list.
As `"0.id"`, `"1.id"` and `"2.id"` all will become `"id"`. And same goes for the other keys.

Answer (score 0):

Substring in this case is a time bomb. Try this!

```js
const jsonFile = [{ "0.id": 1, "0.details.first_name": "Gary", "0.details.last_name": "Ortiz", "0.details.nicknames.0.language": "italian", "0.details.nicknames.0.value": "martello", "0.details.nicknames.1.language": "inglese", "0.details.nicknames.1.value": "hammer", "0.details.email.0": "gortiz0@mapy.cz", "0.details.email.1": "awilliamson1@narod.ru", "0.country": "Indonesia", "0.modified": "2015-05-16", "0.vip": false, "1.id": 2, "1.details.first_name": "Carl", "1.details.last_name": "Jones", "1.details.nicknames.0.language": "danish", "1.details.nicknames.0.value": "wefwgge", "1.details.nicknames.1.language": "Doich", "1.details.nicknames.1.value": "egwrgerge", "1.details.email.0": "erkhoej@google.net", "1.details.email.1": "peeeeeeeeeeweqw@fb.ru", "1.country": "Taiwan", "1.modified": "2325-05-16", "1.vip": false, "2.id": 3, "2.details.first_name": "Michael", "2.details.last_name": "Smith", "2.details.nicknames.0.language": "Portoguese", "2.details.nicknames.0.value": "wdqppppd", "2.details.nicknames.1.language": "Russian", "2.details.nicknames.1.value": "hamfwewdqqmer", "2.details.email.0": "dcwrverg3@iissq.fr", "2.details.email.1": "vvnvncmmxm@dqwdq.com", "2.country": "Japan", "2.modified": "1235-44-44", "2.vip": true }]
        var output = {}
        var mObj = jsonFile[0]
        var mKeys = Object.keys(mObj)
        for (const key of mKeys) {
            let splited = key.split(".")
            let x = splited.shift()
            output[x] = output[x] || {}
            output[x][splited.join(".")] = mObj[key]
        }
        console.log(Object.values(output));
```